# How to query database with engine object without database name

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
_CFG = {
      'user': os.getenv("MYSQL_USER"),
      'password': os.getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
      'host': os.getenv("MYSQL_SERVER"),
      'database': os.getenv("SENSOR_DB"),
      'raise_on_warnings': True
    }
```

Earlier I wrote a function, that would take `_CFG`.

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(**_CFG)
```

and this returns connection object or connection engine !

but later **I realised for some tables I have different database**, and then I decided to **create the connection engine object without**  the `'database': os.getenv("SENSOR_DB")` but that means I would have to specify database name later on to connection !

however at my workplace we do not specify the database name and it gives us query result. Now I have not looked at the API's because I do not have access to it. So I want to know how should I **approach** this, Should I pass database object with access to each table query ? or some other **approach**.

Secondly, I was originally trying to use SQLAlchemy ORM but due to this [reason](https://askubuntu.com/q/1204704/119065) I am not able to install `MySQLDb`.  and I am just sticking to mysql connector for the time being, as this is my home iot infrastucture project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbname.tablename` instead of `tablename` in your queries.

The MySQL protocol still needs a database name during connection, but just use any database you have, like **information_schema** for example. (it's a virtual  database which always exists)

Comment: yes, that is how I plan to do, if I pass database later on I pass it along tablename `dbname.tablename`. I wanted to see if any example API that access database/table.